# How do you get rid of "Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'data-bind' is not a valid attribute of element"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, knockout.js

Is there a nice way I can get rid of this in visual studio 10 when using knockoutjs?  It just pollutes the warnings.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes you can do this in VS 2010 SP1 and VS 11 Developer Preview

> Tools > Options

Select:

> Text Editing > HTML > Validation

And select `XHTML5` or `HTML5` from the drop down list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After doing what Darbio said above, I also add this `<!DOCTYPE/>` on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

First I could not get 'onbefore' events in XHTML Validation So I have changed some options to get rid of XHTML Validation :

For Visual Studio 2008 - Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Validation and switch the validation to [Internet Explorer 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6k9Y.png).

After I can get the ['onbeforepaste'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGpCI.png) event in suggestions.

Comment: visual studio 2008? ouch, why not move to more modern tooling?

Answer (score 0):

After doing what Darbio suggested, I use following code on top of my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```